# Setting up a double opt-in without using any Subscriber List features (publication list, etc.) and just data extension - possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber, publicationlist

Is there a way to set up a double opt-in without the usage of Subscriber List/Publication List?

Instead of the method of linking the Data Extension to the publication list, is there a way to directly manage the subscription status within the Data Extension?

I am asking this question because all the relevant documents/help sources I can find suggest that Subscriber List is an integral part of the opt-in processes, but I want to know if I can just achieve this with using only Data Extension. Do we need to use features like Publication List and Suppression List with Data Extensions because Data Extension alone cannot process and maintain subscription status.

Also it is through Publication List and Suppression List that you can use features such as Subscription and Profile Centers, and you can't set up something similar using Data Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you *can* do it, by having a field for the opt-in status in Data Extension.

Though it means you will need to use AMPscript to update that field through some confirmation Cloud Page, so it's not so out-of-box feature like using Publication Lists or Classic List based double opt-in [feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_double_optin_classiclist.htm&type=5).

As for standard Preference Center - only standard options that you see are available, which means Publication Lists. This is one of the *many* reasons why it's well worth it to build a custom Preference Center.